# Flip a bit in a list of zeros and ones

Tags: python, list

I have a list of randomly generated 0's and 1's. I need to pick a single bit and flip it to its opposite: either a zero to a one or a one to a zero. 
The bitwise not operator only works on integers and long integers, and the xor (`^`) operator works with two integers.

```
Enter a population size: 4
Enter an organism length: 2
[[1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[[1, 1], [0, 1]]]
```

The code above is part of a short user input program where the user inputs pop size and length. The program prints a list of randomly generated numbers with mind to pop size and length and takes the top 50%, which is the second printed list. Now I need to pick a random bit from the second list and flip it to either a zero or a one. Not the whole list, however.

Links and explanations are much appreciated, I'm looking to improve.

Comment: Haven't you tried any code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `randint` to generate a random integer for the index, and then use for instance `^1` to flip it, like:

```
from random import randint

pop = [[1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
individual = pop[1]                            # select the second individual
individual[randint(0,len(individual)-1)] ^= 1  # flip the bit
```

After I ran this, I obtained:

```
>>> pop
[[1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

so it flipped the second bit. But it could have been the first as well. By using `len(individual)` we guarantee that if the number of bits of the individual increases, it will still work.

That been said encoding bits as 0-1s in a list, is not very efficient. You can use `int`s in Python as a list of bits (`int`s have arbitrary length in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)).

**EDIT**

If you want to flip a bit *per* individual (for every individual it can be a *different* bit), you can use a `for` loop:

```
for individual in pop:                             # iterate over population
    individual[randint(0,len(individual)-1)] ^= 1  # flip a random bit
```

If I run this with your given initial population, I get:

```
>>> pop
[[0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

so every individual has exactly one bit flipped, and not all the same one. Of course it is random, so it is possible that at a certain run, the random number generator will pick the same bit for every individual.

Comment: If I want to flip one bit for each organism, how could I do that?

Comment: @tony: the same bit, or a random each time?

Comment: random bit each time

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Comment: individual = new_orgs                        
individual[randint(0,len(individual)-1)] ^= 1
print individual

Comment: @tony: but here you do *not* pick an `individual`. You should write something like `individual = new_orgs[0]` (where `[0]` specifies that you want to alter the first individual).

Comment: Index zero makes sense, but since this is user input I need to alter *every* organism according to user input.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 34, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^=: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: @tony: if you have to alter *every* individual, you should use the `for` loop, so change it to `for individual in new_orgs:` (alter only the first line).

Comment: Right, however I'm still receiving an unsupported operand type for a list and integer

Comment: @tony: what is the `type(new_orgs)`?

Comment: new_orgs is a list

Comment: @tony: but a list of what? A list of individuals? A list of lists of individuals? Can you print a sample `new_orgs`?

Comment: new_orgs is half of the original list orgs, new_orgs is the list with higher fitness values

Comment: new_orgs = []
new_org = orgs[0:(pop_size/2):1]
new_orgs.append(new_org)
print new_orgs

Comment: But then `new_org` is *not* a list of individuals, but a list of lists of individuals... I think you should alter the code how you construct `new_orgs`.

Answer (score 1):

To flip a single bit, use logic arguments.

```
int(not 0) = 1
int(not 1) = 0
```

If you have to flip exactly one bit in every population, I would suggest:

```
chrom = random.choice(pop)
j = random.randrange(len(chrom))
chrom[j] = int(not chrom[j])
```